# Passing javascript function vs use imports in Svelte or React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, svelte

I wanted to use some function from javascript module in one of my component. Should I pass it in props when making the component or should I just use Imports in component itself to get the javascript function?

**Example of Passing in Svelte component:**

**Proxy.js**

```
var Proxy = {
    test: function() {
        .....
    }
}

export default Proxy;
```

**Dashboard.svelte**

```
<script>

export let Proxy;


// use Proxy test function now
</script>
```

**Example of import JS**

**Proxy.js**

```
var Proxy = {
    test: function() {
        .....
    }
}

export default Proxy;
```

**Dashboard.svelte**

```
<script>
import Proxy from "../Proxy.js"

// use Proxy test function now
</script>
```

Which is better way to do in svelte components or any frontend code for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use your `Proxy` module inside of the `<script />` section, then you will need to use `import` just like you would do with any other javascript module.

The `export` keyword used here is special when using Svelte.js. You use it to receive props in your components. Since it appears that `Proxy` is not a prop for a svelte component, then you wouldn't use `export` to include it.

When using React, you would also use `import`. The use of `export` in React is the same as in regular javascript, you don't use it for props.